# Regex Match .Net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Im Using this Code with to Match

```
 var regex = new Regex(@"\[0-9]{3,4}/?\s?\\?\-?_?[A-Z]{2,2}-?\s?/?_?\\?[A-Z]{2,2}");

var match = regex.Match(str);
if (match.Success)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

this string : 1111 CD XZ and Also this one 1111/AB-XZ
But is not working , im on my Intial steps on programming I just yesterday I started to use Regex. Im doing some wrong ?

My Goal Is to Match [The yellow mark on this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bpmf5.png)

Comment: That first backslash is escaping the square bracket.

Comment: Try [`@"\b[0-9]{3,4}(?:\W?[A-Z]{2}){2}\b"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b0-9%5d%7b3%2c4%7d%28%3f%3a%5cW%3f%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%29%7b2%7d%5cb&i=1111+CD+XZ+and+Also+this+one+1111%2fAB-XZ)

Comment: Thank You BOTH. It worked Just Fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is corrupt since the `\` before `[` makes the regex engine match a literal `[` symbol while you wanted to create a character class. Besides, rather than define a sequence of optional chars, you may just define a non-word optional pattern for the separators in your string.

You may use

```
@"\b[0-9]{3,4}(?:\W?[A-Z]{2}){2}\b"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5B0-9%5D%7B3%2C4%7D%28%3F%3A%5CW%3F%5BA-Z%5D%7B2%7D%29%7B2%7D%5Cb&i=1111%20CD%20XZ%20and%20Also%20this%20one%201111%2FAB-XZ)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary (to make sure you really match a 3 to 4 digit sequence later)
- `[0-9]{3,4}` - 3 to 4 digits
- `(?:\W?[A-Z]{2}){2}` - 2 sequences of

  - `\W?` - an optional non-word char (whitespace, punctuation or symbol)
  - `[A-Z]{2}` - 2 uppercase ASCII letters
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

Comment: This is Perfect. this go Beyond what I expected, in my regex I was pending to deal with the (.) but this one solve the complete Issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?i)\d{3,4}[\s\/]\/?[a-z]{2}[-\s][a-z]{2}`